# Capture text after multiple optional strings into named group with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract multiple strings using different patterns from one long string. Here is an example of the input string:

> [Update 2]Number of students: 5[New]Break at 1:45 pm\nStudents involved are: John, Joseph, Maria\nLunch at 2:00pm\nActivities remaining: long jump, shuffle

There are three prefixes which are used to extract the data after it: 'Students involved are:', 'Activities remaining:', 'Number of students:'. I managed to extract the above into a named group using the following Regex:

```
let pattern = /(?<=Number of students: )(?<number>[^\n]+).*?(?<=Students involved are: )(?<students>[^\n]+).*?(?<=Activities remaining: )(?<activities>[^\n]+)/gms
let match = pattern.exec(s)
const num = match.number;
const activities = match.activities;
```

The above works. However, I run into an issue when there is one of the strings missing. All the three prefixes I am searching for are optional. How can I modify the regex to handle optional patterns? Or is there a better way of accomplishing this? Thanks!

Comment: In such cases, it might turn out more convenient to use three separate regexps.

Comment: I considered this. However, since the input is quite a a long string and the code will execute a lot of times, I am looking for an option to use one Regex for performance. Do you think this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need look behind assertions for that use case...

To answer your question you can wrap your individual patterns inside non-capturing groups followed by a question mark:

```
const r = /(?:Desc.1:\s*(?<tag1>.*?))?(?:Descr.2:\s*(?<tag2>.*?))?(?:Desc.3:\s*(?<tag3>.*?))?/
```

If the values can come in any order, you can use a global match and a disjunction:

```
const r = /x(?<tag1>.*)|y(?<tag2>.*)|z(?<tag3>.*)/g

for (const {groups: {tag1, tag2, tag3}} of source.matchAll(r)) {
 ...
}
```

You can see it in action [here](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgZglgNgpgziAXAbVAOwIYFsZJAOgAsAXLKEAGhAGMB7NYmBvEAXwvW10QICsEqdBk2J4hcYgAIATpIC8kgPQAPABQB+ADzEMAcwCMAPnwBKAD4BPDdr0AmY+YBe1nboDMDxboA6aX+Kk4WgBXaWoYeUkAA2UMXwsAI19HaijfXzBaWVUAyWBdaRCABzhEPNd9CklXWyrXN1ZWSVowSSDQ8PwsDGJqQgBBKChVaRMTPN9JcVpYfChaXVVgCrq7VfdWcd9WShA4GFhqYgh6BB4ABkRzgFpLgBYADjYOEEwcPHxqOAEaekZmHhsAC6rCAA)

Also, FYI, the flags you're using don't make a lot of sense to me:

- `g` is useful to match several times (e.g. with `"".matchAll(/regexp/g)`, but it is useless otherwise)
- `m` makes `^` and `$` assertions match the start and end of lines on top of their usual duty, but you're not using them

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
"^\[[^\]]+\](Number of students: )*(?<number>[^\n]+)\\n(Students involved are: )*(?<students>[^\n]+)\\n(Activities remaining: )*(?<activities>[^\n]+)"
```

The differences between mine and yours are the following:

- added `^\[[^\]]+\]` at the beginning to match `[<any characters>]`
- added `*` over the optional parts of your string
- added `\\n` between the paired three parts

I've tested this regex with these two examples:

- `[Update 2]Number of students: 5[New]Break at 1:45 pm\nStudents involved are: John, Joseph, Maria\nLunch at 2:00pm\nActivities remaining: long jump, shuffle`
- `[Update 2]5[New]Break at 1:45 pm\nJohn, Joseph, Maria\nLunch at 2:00pm\nlong jump, shuffle`

Does it work for you?

ps. for any attempt to increased efficiency, more samples of pattern matching are needed

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, this does not work for me at all. Even copying the exact same regex as yours is returning a null. I'm using Firefox to test so perhaps the different environments is the issue.

Comment: Try again using the same regex but without copying the quotes at the beginning and at the end. Are you still getting nulls? (if that's the case, I really don't know: I'm using Firefox too) @John

Comment: https://imgur.com/ycB2FA0

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mNuZiPk

Comment: Left here the images of the two tested examples in regex101.com